# Delete record beetween current date and last week - interval 14 days

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

I have this piece of code, which
- create a folder
- create a backup file
- removes from the db, all data prior to 7 days from the current date

They asked me for a change:
- Given a period of 14 days, delete all data from 8 days to 14

Or rather if today is 2019/04/08, select up to two weeks back
2019/03/25, it eliminates everything that goes from 2019/03/31 and leaves in the db everything that goes from 2019/04/01 to the current date (2019/04/08)

Then it deletes all the previous one in two weeks from 8 days to 14 and leaves on the db everything that goes from the current date to 7 days before.

I know this thing is done with beetween but I can't write the query correctly

```
   <?php
    $databaseHost = 'xxx';
    $databaseName = 'xxx';
    $databaseUsername = 'xxx';
    $databasePassword = 'xxx';
    $connessione = mysqli_connect($databaseHost, $databaseUsername, $databasePassword, $databaseName);



    $query = $connessione->query("
        SELECT *
        FROM utenti
        WHERE data_password < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)

    ");

    $results = $query->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $ok = json_encode($results);

    function makeDirectory($path, $mode)
    {
        // this creates if not exist
        if (!is_dir($path)) {
            return mkdir($path, $mode, true);
        } else {
            echo $path . " already exist!";
        }
    }

    $path = 'backup_LOG';
    $mode = 0777;

    // or you can add here that if exist does not call the function makeDirectory
    if (!is_dir($path)) {
        $risultato = makeDirectory($path, $mode);
    }

    $fileName = 'backup_LOG/backup_file_' . date('Y_m_d') . '.txt';
    $file = fopen($fileName,  'a');
    //$file = fopen($fileName, 'x+');
    fwrite($file, $ok);
    fclose($file);

    if (count($results) > 0) {
        $firstId = reset($results)['data_password'];
        $lastId = end($results)['data_password'];
        $stmt = $connessione->prepare("DELETE FROM utenti WHERE data_password < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)");
        $stmt->bind_param('ii', $firstId, $lastId);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens that `BETWEEN` is not suitable for date values, because it gets an off-by-one error at the end of the range.  Try this query.

```
DELETE 
 FROM utenti 
WHERE data_password >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 14 DAY
  AND data_password < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

This `WHERE` clause accepts every date value on or after midnight fourteen days ago, and every date value before midnight--before the first moment of--seven days ago.

So, if today is 16-Mar-2019, it will take everything with a `data_password` value in the range `2018-03-02 00:00` to `2019-03-08 23:59:59.9999`.

For this to work correctly, the data type of the column must be `DATE`, `DATETIME`, or `TIMESTAMP`. An index on the column can make the query quite fast.

You could use `NOW()` in place of `CURDATE()` if you wanted to delete items that are newer than 14 days ago from now.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM utenti WHERE data_password > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY) AND data_password < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

Also i'm not sure if you column name is right: `data_password`

But regardless that's how I would do it.

You also might need to cast data_password as date if it contains a date like so:

```
DATE(data_password) > ...
```